# Why do I get some arbitrary number when I try to print my (copied) string?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, format-string

I have this struct:

```
struct car{
    char name[9];
};
```

And I have this array:

```
char list_of_names[10][9] = {"toyota", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"};
```

As you can see, I've only typed in the first element; the rest are filler for now. I am trying to copy the first element (toyota) into my struct car "name" variable. Here is what I have tried:

```
//Initialize struct variable
struct car c;
memcpy(c.name, list_of_names[0], 9);
```

I've also tried using strcmp, but every time I try something, the output I get inside c.name is always some random number. I've even tried dereferencing the pointer such as:

```
memcpy(c.name, *(list_of_names[0]), 9);
```

But to no avail; the error is the same. Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Edit**

Here is what I have done to test/print:

```
struct car c;
memcpy(c.name, list_of_names[0], 9);
printf("printing!%d\n", c.name);
```

Output:

```
-13423455 (gibberish)
```

Comment: `memcpy(c.name, list_of_names[0], 9);` appears to be correct. Please post the rest of your code (an [mcve]) since the bug is likely somewhere else.

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that outputs `c.name`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Do you mean `strcpy`; `strcmp` won't work.

Comment: Whatever is wrong is not in the code you posted, except the `memcpy(c.name, *(list_of_names[0]), 9);`

Comment: If you want to print a string, use `%s`, not `%d`.

Comment: Wow, that solved it. How dumb am i

Comment: A decent compiler would warn you about that, if you turn on warnings... hint hint.

Answer (score 4):

Your format string: `"printing!%d\n"` makes `printf()` expect an integer (`%d`) instead of a string (`%s`). That's your bug. What gets printed is a truncated part of the pointer to the first element in the string, as a signed integer.

Comment: Thank you very much. The %d/%s always confuses me, but now I'm sure I'll remember it!

Comment: @DarrelGulseth: If you're using a relatively new comiler, try enabling all the warning (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` with GCC or clang) - that should give you a warning about the mismatch with the format string.

Comment: Got it, will try it out. Thanks once again.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth: Well, you _could_ accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: `s` is for **s**tring, `d` is for **d**ecimal (i.e. base 10)